# Is there any way to remove and insert network module remotely without losing connection?

Tags: linux, networking, driver

I need to ssh to the server, remove the original network driver and insert a new one, but after I remove the original one, the connection will lose.

Is there any way to do it without losing connection.

The thing I want to do is:

```
  $ ssh user@server
  $ sudo rmmod igb
  $ sudo insmod ./igb.ko
```

P.S., igb is the driver for one of Intel ethernet network card.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

```
  $ ssh user@server
  $ sudo rmmod igb; sudo insmod ./igb.ko
```

Here the SSH server in the server will receive both the both commands even before executing the first command.